# Asp.net core 2.1 Role based authorisation not working with JWT

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

I'm currently having an issues where a given client that has a valid claim identity specifying that the client is in the given role, not get authorised for actions and controllers that require that role.

I'm using an API to generate the token which the client will use to access both the API and the website, the tokens are generated as JWT.

I have looked on other posts that have this issue, but almost all of the are using identity which isn't required for this project, since we are using JWT.

I am using HttpContext.Signin to sign in the user, passing it the token received from the API which contains the user's roles and other claims.

I have included the code that's dealing with tokens, and the token received from the API -at the very end-. As clearly seen, the user has the role attribute, yet they are will not be authorised by the authentication middleware.

Creating the token

```
    public async Task<string> CreateBearerTokenAsync(User user, string audience)
    {
        // Create identity for the client
        var claims = await _clientManager.CreateUserClaimsIdentityAsync(user.Id);

        var tokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor
        {
            Subject = claims,
            Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(2),
            IssuedAt = DateTime.UtcNow,
            Issuer = "Bikefy Api",
            Audience = audience,
            SigningCredentials = _encryptionService.TokenSignKey
        };

        // Create the token
        var token = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().CreateJwtSecurityToken(tokenDescriptor);

        // Write the token to string.
        return new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token);
    }
```

Claims identity

```
    public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> CreateUserClaimsIdentityAsync(Guid clientId)
    {
        if (clientId == null || Guid.Empty == clientId)
            throw new ArgumentNullException($"{nameof(clientId)}");

        var user = await GetClientByIdAsync(clientId);
        var id = new ClaimsIdentity("ApiKey", ClaimsIdentity.DefaultNameClaimType, ClaimsIdentity.DefaultRoleClaimType);
        var secKey = await GetSecurityStampAsync(clientId);

        // Add default claims
        id.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, clientId.ToString(), ClaimValueTypes.String));
        if (user.FirstName != null)
            id.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.GivenName, user.FirstName, ClaimValueTypes.String));
        if (user.LastName != null)
            id.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Surname, user.LastName, ClaimValueTypes.String));

        id.AddClaim(new Claim(IdentityProviderClaimType, "Bikey Identity", ClaimValueTypes.String));
        id.AddClaim(new Claim(SecurityStampClaimType, secKey, ClaimValueTypes.String));
        if (user.RoleName != null)
            id.AddClaim(new Claim($"{nameof(User.RoleName)}", user.RoleName, ClaimValueTypes.String));

        // Get roles 
        var roles = await GetRolesAsync(clientId);
        foreach (var role in roles)
            id.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, role));

        // Add user claims
        id.AddClaims(await GetClaimsAsync(clientId));

        return id;
    }
```

Cookie token configuration

```
    public static void ConfigureAuthentication(this IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        var secretKeys = new SecretKeys();
        configuration.GetSection("SecretKeys").Bind(secretKeys);

        var encryptService = new EncryptionService("00E7EB8C24190E2187", secretKeys);
        services.AddSingleton(encryptService);
        services.AddSingleton(secretKeys);

        services.AddAuthentication(x =>
        {
            x.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            x.DefaultChallengeScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;

            x.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;

        }).AddCookie(c =>
        {
            c.Cookie.Name = "CityCyles.Auth";
            c.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
            c.Cookie.Expiration = TimeSpan.FromDays(1);
            c.Cookie.SecurePolicy = Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.CookieSecurePolicy.Always;
            c.LoginPath = $"/Account/Login";
            c.LogoutPath = $"/Account/Logout";
            c.AccessDeniedPath = $"/Account/AccessDenied";
        });

    }
```

User Login

```
        try
        {
            result = await _apiProvider.SendPostRequest(_apiProvider.BuildUrl("Auth", "Authenticate"), apiModel);

            // Convert the string into a token
            var token = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().ReadJwtToken(result);

            // Create cookie options
            var authOptions = new AuthenticationProperties()
            {
                AllowRefresh = model.Remember,
                ExpiresUtc = DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(2),
                IssuedUtc = DateTime.UtcNow,
                IsPersistent = true
            };

            // Get the user claims from the user
            var claimsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(token.Claims, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, ClaimTypes.Name, ClaimTypes.Role);

            // Sign in the user
            await HttpContext.SignInAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, new ClaimsPrincipal(claimsIdentity), authOptions);

            // Redirect the user to the requested page or take them home
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(returnUrl))
                return Redirect(returnUrl);

            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");

        }
        catch (WebException ex)
        {
            _logger.LogWarning(LogEvents.HandlingLogin, ex, "Error  authenticating user.");

            //Display the error
            ModelState.AddModelError("Custom-Error", ex.Message);

            return View(model);
        }
```

Controller Action

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Authorize(Roles = CityCyclesRoles.CityCyclesDocks)]
    public async Task<IActionResult> OnBoard()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

Token

```
{
      "nameid": "3e637f01-85a9-4437-a113-50d2953d014e",
      "given_name": "Stephanie",
      "family_name": "Lee",
      "http://schemas.microsoft.com/accesscontrolservice/2010/07/claims/identityprovider": "Bikey Identity",
      "Bikeyfy.Identity.SecurityStamp": "1b6228cf-945a-4503-a64e-1dcb7b649c22",
      "role": "CityCycles.Staff.Docks",
      "nbf": 1552586386,
      "exp": 1552593586,
      "iat": 1552586386,
      "iss": "CityCycles Api",
      "aud": "CityCycles.Web"
}
```

Comment: Maybe a silly question - but your role in the token is  `CityCycles.Staff.Docks` and the expected role in controller is `CityCyclesRoles.CityCyclesDocks`. Is it the same thing?

Comment: Did you force a sign out/sign in flow after the role was added? Claims are set only during sign in, and the persist as-is.

Comment: @Felix, The `CityCyclesRoles.CityCyclesDocks` is a constant string that has the value `CityCycles.Staff.Docks`.

Comment: @ChrisPratt, yes i have logged out the user after the role was added, and debugged to see the role present in the user's claims when they log in again. So the role exists as the user tries to load the page.